# Yeoman Webapp Generator - Style not loading

Tags: html, css, web-applications, gulp, yeoman

I installed this [generator](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp#readme) through Yeoman, and as far as I know everything has been installed successfully. When I run gulp serve, the default webpage seems to load without style as pictured below. The SASS seems to be compiling into CSS correctly, and both my CSS and HTML have been validated.

Any suggestions? Thanks :)

[image]

Comment: This is an issue, something like this reported here: https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular/issues/1116 . Try run `bower install bootstrap-css --save` in your project dir OR try other suggested solutions.

Comment: Thank you @dNitro! It turns out this worked for me: _"Just edit bower.json and change the bootstrap line to:"_

   `"bootstrap": "3.3.4"`